# Code Coverage in Web Applications (Wicket)

Tags: eclipse, web-applications, wicket, code-coverage, cobertura

I am using Apache Wicket as my web application framework in Eclipse.

Currently I have eCobertura as an eclipse plugin installed.
But it needs a main() method to run. I do not have one.

So how can I run code coverage within a web application?

Regards...

Comment: It's a FAQ: http://cobertura.sourceforge.net/faq.html

Answer (score 0):

Or you can try out EclEmma, it is available in the Eclipse Marketplace and is really easy to use. It gives you a right click option on your project, package or file: "Coverage -> JUnit test".

I use it with Wicket and you don't need any running server or such to run the tests.